# My Emscripten program crashes on return from a function

Tags: c++, emscripten

My emscripten-compiled program crashes with the following error message. The same code runs fine natively when compiled with g++ or clang. By inserting printf statemens I determined that the crash happens in between the last line of function `WebM::initialize()` (called from `main()`) and the next line in function `main()`

```
trap!
trap!

/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:79
      throw ex;
            ^
abort() at Error
    at jsStackTrace (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:1138:13)
    at stackTrace (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:1155:22)
    at abort (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:164948:25)
    at _llvm_trap (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:7136:7)
    at Array.__ZN4WebM10initializeEv [WebM::initialize()] [as 380] (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:8133:3)
    at Object.dynCall_ii (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:162153:43)
    at invoke_ii (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:7282:32)
    at _main (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:7784:5)
    at Object.asm._main (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:162997:21)
    at Object.callMain (/opus_web_audio/build/src/encoder.js:164825:30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error was that the `WebM::initialize()` function could exit without calling a return statement. The compiler warns about this, but I thought it is harmless and ignored it at first.

```
/opus_web_audio/src/main.cpp:178:3: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: If you're going to post and answer your own a question, at least ask *a question*. Your actual post doesn't *ask* anything.

Comment: @WhozCraig "Can you please solve this error for me?" I decided to *Prune pointless queries*, as E. S. Raymond suggests here http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#prune